# Combine Arrays and Hash Tables in PowerShell using data from csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to achieve a data structure in in PowerShell for a particular usecase where data is stored in CSV file in below format

```
MappingName,Param1,Val1,Param2,Val2,Param3,Val3,Param4,Val4
map1,p11,v11,p12,v12,p13,v13,,
map2,p21,v21,p22,v22,,,,
map3,p31,v31,p32,v32,p33,v33,p34,v34
```

I need to parse the csv to have a composite hashmap having mapping name and set of parameters as key value. Also need to access individual key-value pairs for all parameters.

I have achived this successfully in java but not sure how to approach this problem in PowerShell.

Comment: This is not csv, it's fixed width. Did you modify this or copy from excel or something? Sample data needs to be original (ex. file content).

Comment: apologies. Updated the csv content.

Comment: Please show us exactly what you are trying to accomplish in the question and show us anything that you have tried.

Comment: Question should display desired output and your attempts. Also, the CSV is not valid. `Map3` is missing the `param3/value3`-values. Should have been `p32,v32,,,p34,v34`

Comment: appogies again. Thanks for the guidance. I have revised the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are thinking of? It will loop through the properties for each line, group the pairs and add them to a hashtable if there is a value.

```
$data = @"
MappingName,Param1,Val1,Param2,Val2,Param3,Val3,Param4,Val4
map1,p11,v11,p12,v12,p13,v13,,
map2,p21,v21,p22,v22,,,,
map3,p31,v31,p32,v32,,,p34,v34
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#$data = Import-CSV -Path "mycsv.csv"

$out = @()

$data | ForEach-Object { 

    #Hashtable for the parameters
    $ht = @{}

    #List properties
    $_.psobject.Properties |
    #Get only the grouped properties (that have a number at the end)
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\d+$' } |
    #Group properties by param/group number
    Group-Object {$_.Name -replace '\D+(\d+)$', '$1' } | ForEach-Object {
        $param = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'param' }
        $value = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'val' }

        #If property has value
        if($value.value -ne ""){
            #Add to hashtable
            $ht.add($param.Value,$value.Value)
        }
    }

    $ht.add("MappingName",$_.MappingName)

    $out += $ht
}


$out

Name                           Value
----                           -----
p13                            v13
p11                            v11
p12                            v12
MappingName                    map1
p21                            v21
p22                            v22
MappingName                    map2
p32                            v32
p34                            v34
MappingName                    map3
p31                            v31



$out[0]

Name                           Value
----                           -----
p13                            v13
p11                            v11
p12                            v12
MappingName                    map1
```

Personally I would've stored the hashtables in a main hashtable that would use the `MappingName` as key and the hashtable of parameters as value. Ex:

```
$data = @"
MappingName,Param1,Val1,Param2,Val2,Param3,Val3,Param4,Val4
map1,p11,v11,p12,v12,p13,v13,,
map2,p21,v21,p22,v22,,,,
map3,p31,v31,p32,v32,,,p34,v34
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#$data = Import-CSV -Path "mycsv.csv"

$out = @{}

$data | ForEach-Object { 

    #Hashtable for the parameters
    $ht = @{}

    #List properties
    $_.psobject.Properties |
    #Get only the grouped properties (that have a number at the end)
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\d+$' } |
    #Group properties by param/group number
    Group-Object {$_.Name -replace '\D+(\d+)$', '$1' } | ForEach-Object {
        $param = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'param' }
        $value = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'val' }

        #If property has value
        if($value.value -ne ""){
            #Add to hashtable
            $ht.add($param.Value,$value.Value)
        }
    }

    $out.add($_.MappingName,$ht)
}

$out

Name                           Value
----                           -----
map2                           {p21, p22}
map1                           {p13, p11, p12}
map3                           {p32, p34, p31}



PS C:\Users\frode> $out["map2"]

Name                           Value
----                           -----
p21                            v21
p22                            v22
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. This is exactly what I am looking for. Can you please explain a bit on the last comment - "Personally I would've stored the hashtables in a main hashtable that would use the MappingName as key and the hashtable of parameters as value." I have used similar approach in java using composite hasmap but not sure how to do that in powershell.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you very much!!